# Why does a custom splice function outperform native splice when the array size is lower than 3-5000?

Tags: javascript, native, splice, jsperf

I'm writing an implementation of A* path-finding for a game, and are trying to find the fastest way of inserting values into an array of integers. I've made a custom splice function, and tested it against the native one.

If the array size is below about 3-5000, the custom function outperforms the native (on chrome). The result is useful for me, because I can select the best function based on the array size, but I don't understand why native is better on larger arrays, and custom on smaller. Can you explain why?

Test is here:
https://jsperf.com/native-splice-vs-custom

Custom splice function:

```
function splice(ary, index, value) {
    let newValue = value;
    let newIndex = index;
    let nextValue = ary[newIndex + 1];
    while(nextValue !== undefined) {
      ary[newIndex] = newValue;
      newValue = nextValue;
      nextValue = ary[++newIndex];
    }
  }
```

Comment: With your test case native is faster for me for 87,950 vs 78,552

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. When I ran it, the custom implementation was slower by 40%.

Comment: For me the native implementation was ~50% slower, on Chrome 58 (ubuntu). (I did 5 runs). But your `splice` implementation doesn't meet all requirements a `splice` implementation should have.

Comment: Hmm, good to know that the test-results can vary. Is JSperf dependent on the computer? As for the implementation, the splice function  only need to meet the requirements of the path finding function (the faster the better).

Comment: When I test it, the native is 60% slower.

Comment: And native is 90% slower on firefox...